# new .net 4 multi-threading technique?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, screen-scraping

i sat in on part of a Microsoft PDC and heard the presenter talk about the cool new way that .net 4 and VS2010 allow for multi-threading. the code is smaller and cleaner and simpler,  the logic is easier and it performs better with more control with regards to thread waiting, aborting and the such...

i have not yet used multi-threading in my apps and was looking to make a sample application that would lend itself to this and came up with a screen scraper that would take a a URL and extract all the links/ urls on the page and follow them recursively all the while storing feedback of the url that is being acted on to a DB table or in memory list object.

can anyone post a sample code spinet or url that explains the new features of multi threading using asp.net with C# please.

(any hints on how to go about the actual screen scraping would be nice also)

Comment: Do you mean the PDC just gone? If so, they may have been talking about C# 5's async handling rather than "just" the new threading in .NET 4 (which is already a big improvement).

Comment: I assume you saw something about `async` and `await` which is a feature of an upcoming C# version (i.e. it is *not* available in .NET 4.0, you will have to download the Async CTP to use the feature).

Comment: You should check out parallel computing on the .NET framework.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/ee847320.aspx

Comment: C#5 is the upcoming C# version (It's not an official name yet so you won't find any official documentation about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should check out [Reed's site](https://reedcopsey.com/). He has a series of blogs explaining the topic.

Eric Lippert has examples too as he talks about the differences between C# 4 and C# 5 in this regard [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017040918/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx).